# SetinputType to TextInputEditText from XML

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using  this **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout** for editText.

issue is when i try to set this **android:inputType="textCapSentences"** from XMl it's not working but when i set programmatically it's working.

Whats the issue with that property?

Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dip"
                            android:layout_weight="0.4"
                            android:id="@+id/tilFPCode"
                            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/style_EditText_ErrorStyle"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/style_EditText_HintStyle"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:maxLength="5"
                                android:id="@+id/etFPCode"
                                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"
                                android:hint="@string/forgot_sec_code_hint"
                                style="@style/style_EditText"/>

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Did you set it on the `<TextInputLayout>`, or the `<TextInputEditText>`?

Comment: Please check my question i updated XML code

Comment: OK, I was just checkin', because you only mentioned `TextInputLayout` in the question body. Did you try it without the `android:textAllCaps="true"`?

Comment: yes i do same without `android:textAllCaps="true"` this
but i got same problem

Answer (score 0):

You must apply `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` in your edit text directly like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/XXX"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Also you can replace TextInputEditText with EditText

Answer (score -2):

try this code

.java class

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

xml file

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

Comment: He wants capitalized sentences!!

Comment: i have done with this code ,as i said it's working but i wanted to do from XML side